# What does system_u means when assigned to a file?

Tags: linux, rhel, selinux

What my question is :

1. if there is a file assigned with system_u as SELinux that means only the user mapped to system_u/unconfined_u gets to access the file?
2. if this label is assigned to an executable that means anyone who runs this exec starts a process with system_u/system_r label?
3. or system_u or system_r assigned to a file doesn't mean anything, it's just a placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if there is a file assigned with system_u as SELinux that means only the user mapped to system_u/unconfined_u gets to access the file?

That depends on the security model, but generally the user attribute in a security context is only used to glue the remainder of a security context to Linux user/group identities. This security model is called Identity-based access control. The attributes main purpose is to address the challenge of: How do we enhance/extend/modernize the existing Linux access control model? IBAC is what connects the two.

But alternatively the user attribute can additionally also be used to separate entities based on SELinux user identities (IBAC-separation). This security model is usually not enabled though (but the selinux reference policy has this option).

> if this label is assigned to an executable that means anyone who runs this exec starts a process with system_u/system_r label?

No but (I think) it could. The default behavior is customizable in the security policy with what are called "default rules". The default is that when you execute a file, your new process inherits the identifier associated with the user attribute in a security context from the "calling process".

See: https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux-notebook/blob/main/src/default_rules.md#default_user

> or system_u or system_r assigned to a file doesn't mean anything, it's just a placeholder?

You will almost never see system_r associated with files. Instead you might see object_r associated with files. object_r is indeed a place holder to fill in the selinux role security attribute field in a security context associated with objects. This is because by default roles are used to implements a security model called "role-based access control" and this model applies to user processes only and not to files. You can optionally and additionally use this attribute to enforce a custom security model like for example RBAC-separation, where you separate access to files based on role identifiers.

Every field in a security context has at least one meaning. The attributes and identifiers associated with these fields correspond to security models and security models are "designs to address particular security challenges". The only exception is the object_r role identifier, but even that has a meaning because it tells me that there is no separation of access to files based on roles.

- RBAC https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux-notebook/blob/main/src/rbac.md#role-based-access-control
- IBAC https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux-notebook/blob/main/src/users.md#selinux-users
- TE https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux-notebook/blob/main/src/type_enforcement.md#type-enforcement
- MLS https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux-notebook/blob/main/src/mls_mcs.md#multi-level-and-multi-category-security
- Security context https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux-notebook/blob/main/src/security_context.md#security-context